# How do i request notification permission from the user for Android devices?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging API on my app. When triggering this function below, it requests for user permission on iOS devices.

```
import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";

const requestNotificationPermission = async () => {
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
}
```

However that's not the case for Android devices. I have to manually enable app notifications from the Settings. I read that you do not need permissions for push notifications but I don't get the notifications unless the setting is manually enabled. How do I request for user permissions on Android?

I also tried adding related permission to the manifest file however it didn't really help.

Comment: You need to ask permission for android as well. Can you tell, when are you calling the requestNotificationPermission function?

Comment: @this.arjun As soon as the app starts. and it actually returns that it's already authorized even though it's disabled in the settings.

Comment: if it's already authorized try fetching the device token with const token = await messaging().getToken(); then use this token to send a test notification on your device. Also make sure, you have subscribed to the event listeners for receiving the notification.

Comment: Just found out that it requests permission after opening the app ONLY IF the user receives a push notification beforehand (app must be in the background when the notification is received). which means user won't see the initial notification unless it's enabled manually.

Answer (score 0):

I found that with Android API 33+ notification permissions now need to be requested manually.
[Android - Requesting permissions](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#android---requesting-permissions)

The Firebase suggested built-in react-native [PermissionAndroid](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.70/permissionsandroid) API had the *POST_NOTIFICATION: 'android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS'* permission added in version .70

Comment: is there an alternative way on doing this other than updating react-native to .70? Google Play store now only accepts android api 33+ and updating our react native app to .70 seems kind of impossible right now.

Comment: @JohhanSantana
I believe you can use typecasting to get around this issue until you upgrade to .70+ version of React Native. Import the Permission type from react-native and cast the user-permission value that should be added to the AndroidManifest.xml.


`import { Permission, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

PermissionsAndroid.request('android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS' as Permission)`